# java selenium navigate through a webpage using xpath

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to use selenium to make a login, navigate, fill a form and download a file.
When i'm trying to navigate i need to click a link, sounds pretty basic.
Since it has no id or name, i used FirePath to get the xPath(`.//*[@id='id25']/li[4]/a`) then i did the following:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='id25']/li[4]/a"));
```

Selenium returns me  **Unable to locate element:**
I did some reading here and there and tried a few different things:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Network Support")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Network Support']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".LI_Primary"));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("[@id='id25']/li[4]/a"));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/span/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/ul/li[4]/a")).click();
```

None of those work, selenium always return **"Unable to locate element:"**

**The html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>

    <head id="Head1"></head>
    <frameset id="EbpFrame" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" rows="111px,*">
        <frame style="border:0px !important;" noresize="noresize" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="upper" src="/general/UpperNavigationRibbon.aspx?header=noname">
            #document
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <!--

                [if lte IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]

                -->
                <!--

                [if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]

                -->
                <!--

                [if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]

                -->
                <!--

                [if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!

                -->
                <html>
                    <!--

                    <![endif]

                    -->
                    <head id="Head1"></head>
                    <body class="header" onload="SetFrameHeight()">
                        <form id="formm" action="UpperNavigationRibbon.aspx?header=noname" method="post">
                            <div class="aspNetHidden"></div>
                            <div class="aspNetHidden"></div>
                            <span id="spanContent">
                                <div id="page_container" class="header">
                                    <ul id="global_nav"></ul>
                                    <div id="primary_links">
                                        <a class="eLogo" title="Home" href="javascript:menu_Controll('/Portal/Home.aspx')"></a>
                                        <div style="width:810px">
                                            <div id="primary_nav">
                                                <ul id="id25" class="clearfix">
                                                    <li></li>
                                                    <li></li>
                                                    <li></li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a class="LI_Primary" title="Network Support" href="javascript:menu_Controll('/ContactAndhelp/ContactsAdmin.aspx?CategoryID=10')"></a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="clientLogo"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="bottomgrad"></div>
                            </span>
                            <input id="hdnSerVar" type="hidden" value="fjunior@timbrasil.com.br" name="hdnSerVar"></input>
                        </form>
                        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
                    </body>
                </html>
        </frame>
        <frame style="border:0px !important;" onload="AppBodyTrackHistory()" noresize="noresize" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" scrolling="auto" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="portalmain" src="/Portal/Home.aspx"></frame>
    </frameset>

</html>
```

Comment: Well, do path expressions work at all with your code? What about `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*"));`?

Comment: @MathiasMüller i tried using xpath to make a log in, worked fine(its on the same class btw), but i'm using then whit ID, since its easier to read.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select a frame using selenium?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366689/how-to-select-a-frame-using-selenium)

Comment: @louis, it became with the edits comments and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies whitin the frames, as it can be seen here: [How to select a frame using selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366689/how-to-select-a-frame-using-selenium)

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("upper")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='id25']/li[4]/a")).click();
```

Using the above will make selenium select the frame you need, and then click the link you want.

Answer (score 0):

After completing your html (it wasn't well formed) the xpath worked properly and found the element you want.
Tested using http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath

**EDIT**

This is a html that works. Don't know if it's exactly your page..

```
<document>
<html>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head id="Head1"/>
<body class="header" onload="SetFrameHeight()">
<form id="formm" action="UpperNavigationRibbon.aspx?header=noname" method="post">
<div class="aspNetHidden"/>
<div class="aspNetHidden"/>
<span id="spanContent">
<div id="page_container" class="header">
<ul id="global_nav">
<div id="primary_links">
<a class="eLogo" title="Home" href="javascript:menu_Controll('/Portal/Home.aspx')"/>
<div style="width:810px">
<div id="primary_nav">
<ul id="id25" class="clearfix">
<li/>
<li/>
<li/>
<li>
<a class="LI_Primary" title="Network Support" href="javascript:menu_Controll('/ContactAndhelp/ContactsAdmin.aspx?CategoryID=10')">Network Support</a>
</li>
<li/>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</ul>
</div>
</span>
</form>
</body>
</html>
</document>
```

Comment: Saying "it wasn't well formed" does not suffice as an answer, in my opinion. Could you also say what exactly was wrong and present a correct version of the HTML - and the XPath result?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put here the HTML I used

Comment: ?? I'm gettin the html from the site i'm acessing, i'm just omitting whats below since it doesn't provide any help full information, and although it passed on the xpathtester my questions is why it doesn't work on the code.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry. Thought you had pasted everything there.

Comment: Have you tried "li[position()=4]" instead of "li[4]"?

Comment: I added some extra information, i'm only able to see that html if i use inspect on the page, if i use ctrl+u i get a different one. My guess is selenium is not being able to see that html...