# Is it possible to click "OK" on an invisible pop up frame in selenium? python

Tags: python, selenium, frame, invisible

I need to click "OK" on a pop up to sign in to costar.com.

When the frame pops up, it freezes the rest of the window and does't allow me to look at developer tools to see the elements.

After looking at the source code, I found that it is an invisible frame.

If you want to see for yourself:
-go to costar.com
-click login
-click login button

You will see the type of invisible frame I'm talking about. Using chrome to search the source code, you can find the invisible frame information searching for "invisible" or "certificate".

Is it possible to interact with that frame?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: i guess you need  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366689/how-to-select-a-frame-using-selenium

Comment: I'm not seeing any popup.Are you talking about the alert when no credentials were given.

Comment: @Madhan yes that alert. It is the same style of alert that pops up when I plug in the correct credentials, except it gives me the option to click "OK".

Comment: how would you interact with the alert when no credentials were given?

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting is [alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003003/check-if-any-alert-exists-using-selenium-with-python)

You have to switch to the alert and accept it

```
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.accept()
```

Comment: I tried that, but nothing happened. The alert is invisible, so I can't figure out how to switch to it. (selenium can't see that it's there)

Answer (score 0):

Try also:

```
driver.switch_to_frame("frame")
```

or something like this

```
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```

Comment: For some reason, nothing seems to work.  It seems like selenium can't detect that there's a partial stop in the ajax before opening the new page.  The alert causes the entire frame to freeze, which stops me from being able to inspect the elements.  It also times out when searching for frames or windows.

Comment: It looks like their web is blocking webdriver techniques "on purpose". Depending on your needs, there may be better approach, e.g. jmeter, working on http (transfer) layer.