# Can't find button with text() in selenium chromedriver python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I cannot click on the button but every method I tried has failed.
Here is the result of clicking "inspect" in chrome:

```
<button class="rg-run-report-button md-raised md-primary md-ink-ripple md-button" type="submit" ng-transclude="" ng-click="reportCtrl.generateReport()" ng-disabled="!(reportCtrl.isGenerateButtonEnabled())">
        RUN REPORT
      <div class="md-ripple-container" style=""></div></button>
```

I am going off of this and building an Xpath like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'RUN REPORT')]").click()
```

The text "RUN REPORT" has a lot of awkward whitespace around it. I am not sure what to do since I have tried to locate the button via its attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of following locators - 
following locator will remove spaces around the text and look for text only

```
//button[normalize-space(text()='RUN REPORT')]
```

or from the html structure it seems your application is angular for application developed in angular using `ng` tags is quite effective

```
//button[@ng-click="reportCtrl.generateReport()"]
```

Comment: I got a NoSuchElement exception when I tried both. I am not sure what else to try. Thank you! @Dev

Comment: use wait condition before checking for element and check if element is inside frame, if yes then you need to select frame first

Comment: I am using a wait right now, but what do you mean by "select frame first" and how would you go about doing that? When I watch the driver's actions the page that the button is on is loaded before the clicking action.

Comment: there are iframes on webpage which are hidden and cant see by open eyes manytimes , if web elements are inside iframe we need to select iframes first then look for elements inside iframes

Comment: how would you select iframes?

Comment: here you go - https://stackoverflow.com/q/18366689/5400362 and for better understanding  -  read this thread - https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html

Comment: I appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: I did as you suggested and hunted around a bit to find the right iframe. It worked! I used the ng-click example you gave for the Xpath and it worked too! THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @Dev:

The issue with finding the element that I needed to click was not from an incorrect Xpath locator, but not thinking to switch iframes. The source that I was looking at did not contain the element directly, but did have one iframe (out of two total) that did.

When I clicked "inspect element" on the button, it didn't show me the components directly. BECAUSE the components were nested in an iframe.

I did:

```
driver.switch_to.frame('name of iframe')
```

THEN

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@ng-click='reportCtrl.generateReport()']")
```